# Is Max Secure software malware?

Tags: malware, spybot-sd

I'm working on fixing a friend's computer. It has problems.

I just ran Spybot S&D and it said that the supposed "RegistryCleaner" and "SpywareDetector" that they just purchased are really malware. they are both by a company called MaxSecure.

Does anyone know about them? Spybot says that it is related to Smitfraud-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They aren't malware, they've even have had [reviews in PC Magazine](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2073458,00.asp). The software might not be the greatest out there, but it definitely isn't malware. Probably just a false positive. I've used their [spyware encyclopedia](http://www.spywaredetector.net/spywareweremove.htm) before and it's very well kept with legitimate information.

Comment: Softpedia is with you on this one, but unlike McAfee or Safer Networking, they aren't a IT security company: http://www.softpedia.com/get/Others/Signatures-Updates/Max-Secure-Spyware-Detector-Threat-Definitions.shtml

Comment: Their free demo versions I would classify as spyware for the weird actions it performs to get you to buy the software, but their paid versions are not.

Answer (score 1):

This is what [Spybot Search & Destroy](http://forums.spybot.info/showthread.php?t=37717) reports when found:

> Description:
>   SpywareDetector seems to be in close relation to Smitfraud-C. It is installed together with Smitfraud-C. and pretends to be an anti virus solution. Scanning with SpywareDetector will return viruses found (that were installed before by SpywareDetector) but the user cannot remove them without buying the full version for about EUR 20. As SpywareDetector is often installed with Smitfraud-C. against the user's will, full alertness is essential.*

I just now had to clean three entries from my computer that was definitely malware and placed there by SpywareDetector.

When a program is inside of another program and then inserts itself to your system (system files and registry) and is placed there to deliver information to its owner about you and your buying/surfing activities, that is not *ONLY* **malware**, that is a **TROJAN**!

Here's another [Spybot S&D report](http://forums.spybot.info/showthread.php?t=53837) regarding MaxSecure RegistryCleaner.

**[McAfee](http://www.siteadvisor.com/sites/maxpcsecure.com)** declared their website as unsafe:

> McAfee TrustedSource web reputation analysis found potential security risks with this site. Use with extreme caution.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the advice. I ended up having to replace the hard drive (it failed soon after posting this), but I will _strongly_ advise them not to go with this product.

Thanks, guys! +1